# mySQL jdbc record retrieval inside for-loop in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, nullpointerexception

this is what i am doing:

```
String[] output = new String[index.length];

     try{   
       for(int i=0; i<index.length; i++){
          Statement st = con.createStatement();
          ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(
              "SELECT url FROM resources WHERE rid = "+(index[i]);

        while(res.next()){
           output[i] = res.getString("url"); //<-- this is where exception is thrown
       }
    } catch(...)
```

---

The Method is working but instead of printing the correct url value, it is priting someting like this:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@85af80
```

What does it mean? The url field in mySQL is VarChar, it worked fine with above methods but in this loop why i am getting the above result??

Comment: I hope you're absolutely sure that index[i] is not under user control, otherwise you should really fix that SQL injection attack vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't initialized `output[]`!

Try this:

```
String[] output = new String[index.length];
```

That strange output is caused by printing the *array*, ie `System.out.println(output);`

Try this instead:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
```

It's kinda lame, but java doesn't automatically print the array *contents*, it prints the object type and address. The hint is the letter `L` at the start, which it uses to indicate an array

Comment: you might not know the size of the result set during runtime. I suggest using a List instead of a fixed sized array of String.

Comment: Thank you. I have done so but now facing this strange output problem. Can you suggest what could be the case.

Comment: @gouki He does know the size at runtime: it's exactly the same size as the index array - as per the code

Comment: Im sorry, i got it. The problem was not because of this code (after initializing the array) rather i was not using the index[] just printing the array without index.